# 2 way selection switch for up to 30 kV

Tags: switches, high-voltage

I am looking for a mechanical 2 way selection switch which is rated up to 30kV / 10 A (pulsed, pulse length 100 micro-secs). It could be something like mechanical switches (e.g. the polarity switch of the old Fluke HV supplies https://www.ebay.com/itm/FLUKE-410B-HIGH-VOLTAGE-POWER-SUPPLY-0-10K-VDC-0-10-MA-/361503203404). I do not have any special performance criteria (switching time, etc.) and it does not need hot-switching capabilities.

I searched already for some time, but did not find anything fitting my needs in the web.

Comment: The most important question is does it have to switch with voltage applied (like a power supply switch doesn't) so breaking is required, or cold, so only voltage withstanding is needed.

Comment: Hi Neil, good point: only cold, no need to hot-switch

Comment: an automobile distributor? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributor

Comment: @Jasen: I rather thought of some less fancy device. Some normal know-switch (I don't know the proper English terminology)

Answer (score 1):

Would a high voltage relay do? Seem pretty simple to engineer something like this Ross one out PCB material.

[image]